# Matching duplicate cells

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Final()
Dim var As Double
var = ActiveCell.Value

Range("B2:J10").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete

If var <> 0 Then
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:=var
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("B2").Select
Else
    Range("B2").Select
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

The above code was given to my by a member Jay Mangal and this will highlight numbers that are selected and will show all numbers that match, but it is coded to change Format Conditions and it deletes any conditional formatting I have. Can it be change to just highlight the numbers and do nothing else.

Comment: Delete line Selection.FormatConditions.Delete, that will keep any existing conditional format you already have. However, running the code multiple times will add the same formatting condition every time.

Comment: jonady, any numbers highlight doesn't go away